# flutter, Firebase Firestore I can't add element in the list

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i'm trying to add a userID in the _thumbnailList
but it doesn't work.
I have no idea

```
List<DocumentSnapshot> _thumbnailList;
List<DocumentSnapshot> get thumbnailList => _thumbnailList;

...

  void addRecommendListLocalAndServerInSearchProduct(
      {@required String productId,
      @required String loginUserUid,
      @required List<Product> productLIst}) async {

    List<dynamic> recommendList = [];
    String uploaderId;

    _thumbnailList.forEach((element) {
      if (element.data['productId'] == productId) {
        print(
            'thumbnail recommendUidList is  ${element.data['recommendUidList']}');
        ✅ element.data['recommendUidList'].add('dasda'); //for testing 
        print('︎thumbnail after added ${element.data['recommendUidList']}');
      }
    });

...
```

I call the method like this.

```
// user already recommend this
          if (_isRecommend) {
            setState(() => _isRecommend = false);
            productsProvider.removeRecommendListLocalAndServerInSearchProduct(
              productId: _productId,
              productLIst: _loadedProducts,
              loginUserUid: _loginUserId,
            );
          }

// user haven't recommend this 
          else {
            setState(() => _isRecommend = true);
            productsProvider.addRecommendListLocalAndServerInSearchProduct(
              productId: _productId,
              loginUserUid: _loginUserId,
              productLIst: _loadedProducts,
            );
          }
```

recommendUidList is List

after I print it, in console there is a just empty List
like [ ]

you guys any idea about this bug ? any. clue?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to upload a single document, directly to your firestore?

In that case use this source code here:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart' as firebase_storage;
import 'package:path/path.dart';

typedef OnCompleteFirebaseUpload = Function(String cloudPath);

void uploadDocument(String filePath, OnCompleteFirebaseUpload complete,
      Function onError) async {
    firebase_storage.Reference firebaseDocument =
        firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(
            'sample_directory/${basenameWithoutExtension(filePath)}_${DateTime.now().toIso8601String()}.txt');
    firebaseDocument
        .putFile(File(filePath))
        .whenComplete(
            () async => complete(await firebaseDocument.getDownloadURL()))
        .catchError((e){
          //Manage your error here
        });
  }
```

The text file that you are uploading to the firestore will contain the userID that you are trying to upload. In this case, the google firestore is acting as a remote blob storage container. It must contain a file, even it where using object storage, where the UserID was metadata to a file, you would still have to collect the entire file, then add the metadata, and upload it again as one whole object.

Comment: thanks for your reply 
it's pretty difficult to understand my question. I guess
because i didn't upload my whole code i cut the code 
so... i think you misunderstood about my question . 

thanks though 

Comment: if the answer still helped you in anyway, do you mind still voting it up? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution
If someone has same problem , i hope it'll help

[image]

as you can see i used ***final*** that's why 
man... i wasted my 3hours